# HTTP Connection Pool error (Max retries exceeded) with url in requests module

Tags: python, autologin

I attempt for log in to a website by requests module in python. This is my python code:

```
import requests

url='http://example.com/login.php' 
Data={'user':'user_name','pass':'my_password'} 
session=requests.session() 
req=session.post(url=URL, data=Data)
```

after run this, get below error:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /login.php (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Replace `example.com` with the real host name! Or case you just used it as a dummy: Check the host name you entered and your internet connection!

Comment: I try this code with multiple host name, but any time get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, its the proxy which is creating hindrance.
You can do it by adding proxy as an argument while you are passing url.

```
import requests
site = "yourscrappingsite.com"
proxies = {"https": "http://yourprox.com:PortNo"}
page = requests.get(url=site,proxies=proxies)
```

This should work for you. Let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Python variables are case sensitive. Your variable is lowercase `url` but in `session.post` method you set `url` parameter to uppecase `URL`. That can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem. In my case the URL was wrong, like this:

API = 'http://http://localhost:54057/api'